# The page does not load when I press the tab link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

The page does not load when I first click on the 'All' tab. Blank page loading. It comes when clicked for the second time. How can I get it to load on the first click?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
    <li><a asp-action="OverTimeRequest" asp-controller="FazlaMesai">Fazla Mesai Talebi</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="getAllOvertimeListFilter(durum='Beklemede')" href="#menu1">Waiting</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="getAllOvertimeListFilter(durum='Reddedildi')" href="#menu2">Cancel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have JavaScript manipulating those tabs?

Comment: no I don't have and I dont know how can I add in Javascript

Comment: Can you show more about your view?Such as #home.Where you put it?And do you have any error in console?

Comment: No, I Don't have error. #menu1 is like that.   When I click this layer, the blank page comes first and then # menu1 loads. I need it when I first click.

 <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <table id="exampleOnay" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>

                                </thead>
                            </table>  </div>
                    </div>

Comment: You say you `first click on the 'All' tab. Blank page loading`,and the tab is `href="#home"`,Why you say you click will get menu1?

Comment: In fact, the overtimerequest page is loaded when the page is first loaded.I have authorized all part and only they can see it. How can I switch from the "All" tab to the "waiting" tab with one click?

Comment: What is your `getAllOvertimeListFilter(durum='Beklemede')`?